# Get Instance Of ViewController From AppDelegate In Swift

Tags: ios, swift, appdelegate

I am trying to load a specific ViewController from the app delegate in swift when a user clicks a UILocalNotification. I have figured out that this is called in this function:

```
func application(application: UIApplication!, didReceiveLocalNotification notification: UILocalNotification!)
```

But when I try and access one of the open ViewControllers I think it's returning null because my application is crashing. Here is what I am trying:

```
var rootViewController = self.window!.rootViewController
var storyBoard = rootViewController.storyboard
var setViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("CurrentShows") as ViewController_CurrentShows

rootViewController.navigationController.popToViewController(setViewController, animated: false)
setViewController.reloadData()
```

It's crashing on the popToViewController line.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You could try:

```
let rootViewController = self.window!.rootViewController
let mainStoryboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let setViewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("CurrentShows") as! DetailViewController
rootViewController?.navigationController?.popToViewController(setViewController, animated: false)
```

**Swift 3:**

```
let mainStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let controller = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "viewController")
self.present(viewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: I tried using this inside a function and it didn't work, I'm using xcode7 and swift2. do you mind updating the code above please.

Comment: @suisied Might be worth creating a question on StackOverflow and linking to it as we can't really diagnose your issue without seeing your code.

Comment: not working in swift 2.. impossible to get "Main" storyboard.