# Swift - pushViewController from appDelegate, rootViewController.navigationController is nil

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, appdelegate

Having a problem following a few guides, specifically
http://blog.originate.com/blog/2014/04/22/deeplinking-in-ios/

I'm setting the url scheme and it's working well to launch the app from another app, but passing in the host or url are not working as it seems it should. I'm using storyboards and interface builder for all the view layouts.

The guide shows this openURL in appDelegate:

```
-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation{
    if([[url host] isEqualToString:@"page"]){
        if([[url path] isEqualToString:@"/page1"]){
            [self.mainController pushViewController:[[Page1ViewController alloc] init] animated:YES];
        }
    return YES;
    }
}
```

Here is my version simplified and in swift from a few other sources, ie 
[Get Instance Of ViewController From AppDelegate In Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24638376/get-instance-of-viewcontroller-from-appdelegate-in-swift) I'm skipping the conditional for the url host at the moment to remove potential other variables in the problem.

```
func application(application: UIApplication, openURL url: NSURL, sourceApplication: String, annotation: AnyObject?) -> Bool {
    var rootViewController = self.window!.rootViewController
    let mainStoryboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    var profileViewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("profile") as ProfileViewController

    rootViewController.navigationController.popToViewController(profileViewController, animated: true)

    return true

}
```

The swift version causes a crash:
`fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`

It seems that rootViewController doesn't have a navigationController yet?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

It seems that rootViewController actually is of type UINavigationController in my case, so casting it on declaration allowed me to call pushToViewController directly on it.

```
func application(application: UIApplication, openURL url: NSURL, sourceApplication: String, annotation: AnyObject?) -> Bool {
    let rootViewController = self.window!.rootViewController as! UINavigationController
    let mainStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let profileViewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "InstructionVC") as! InstructionVC
    rootViewController.pushViewController(profileViewController, animated: true)
    return true

}
```

Comment: I know this has been up for a year but i was wondering, if you push to a new view controller you instantiated, does this count as a segue where you can prepareforsegue?

Comment: Thank you thank you thank you. Was following some guides that were just grabbing the nav controller from the storyboard and it just wasn't working and this was the trick!

Answer (score 26):

**SWIFT 4:** *Safe way to push with the use of conditional binding and Chaining*

```
if let navController = self.navigationController, let viewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "indentfier") as? CustomViewController{
    navController.pushViewController(viewController, animated: true)
}
```

In One line of code :

**Swift 3:**

```
self.navigationController!.pushViewController(self.storyboar‌​d!.instantiateViewCo‌​ntroller(withIdentif‌​ier: "view2") as UIViewController, animated: true)
```

---

```
self.navigationController!.pushViewController(self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("view2") as UIViewController, animated: true)
```

Comment: Swift 2.0        `self.navigationController!.pushViewController(self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("view2") as! UIViewController, animated: true)`

Comment: Swift 3.0
self.navigationController!.pushViewController(self.storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "view2") as UIViewController, animated: true)

Comment: self.navigationController is nil. how you push?

Comment: @Umitk PushViewController is a part of Navigation API. So without 'UINavigationController' you cont push any.
Updated answer to safest way to handle the push

Answer (score 9):

APPDELEGATE TO PAGE:

```
        let mainStoryboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let loginPageView = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("leadBidderPagerID") as! LeadBidderPage
        var rootViewController = self.window!.rootViewController as! UINavigationController
        rootViewController.pushViewController(loginPageView, animated: true)
```

PAGE TO PAGE:

```
        let loginPageView = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("scoutPageID") as! ScoutPage
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(loginPageView, animated: true)
```

Comment: This was the only helpful post I saw in hours. Thanks. Page-to-page was what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Updated for swift 3/4.
The most voted "one line of code" doesn't work because there's no navigation controller in "self"

```
let rootViewController = self.window!.rootViewController as! 
UINavigationController
let mainStoryboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let profileViewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ProfileViewController") as! ProfileViewController
rootViewController.pushViewController(profileViewController, animated: true)
```

Comment: I dont find window in your solutin

Comment: @RishabhDugar Are you in AppDelegate class?

Comment: No I am in my Controller File

Comment: The solution is for getting the navigation controller from app delegate, not for view controller. In your case, the "one line of code" solution above might be what will work for you.

Comment: Signal SIGABRT on line rootViewController

Answer (score 2):

Swift 3 & 4 best practices to push viewcontroller from AppDelegate:

```
if let rootViewController = self.window!.rootViewController as? UINavigationController {
   let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

   if let viewcontroller = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "DiscussionBoardSID") as? DiscussionBoardViewController {
      viewcontroller.postID = "13" ///pass data to your viewcontroller
      rootViewController.pushViewController(viewcontroller, animated: true)
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to present and dismiss with NavigationBar or Dismiss(Animated: true, completion: nil)
Set *addObserver* in **didFinishLaunchingWithOptions**

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {



NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(devolucionNoPresencial), name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "DevolucionNoPresencial"), object: nil)
        return true
}
```

then in your method

```
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
//do your code for .active, .inactive .background, etc

 if let userInfo = response.notification.request.content.userInfo as? [String : AnyObject] {
            if UIApplication.shared.applicationState == .active {
//activate the notificationCenter so you can call your @objc method
NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "DevolucionNoPresencial"), object: nil)
}
```

add @objc method

```
@objc private func devolucionNoPresencial() {


       //change DevolucionVC for VC you want to present

        if let controller = DevolucionVC() as? DevolucionVC {
            if let window = self.window, let rootViewController = window.rootViewController {
                var currentController = rootViewController
                while let presentedController = currentController.presentedViewController {
                    currentController = presentedController
                }
                currentController.present(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
func pushNewView() {
    if let wind = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate?.window {
        if let rootViewController = wind?.rootViewController {
            let viewToPush = YourViewController()
            let nav1 = UINavigationController(rootViewController: viewToPush)
            if let alreadySomeOneThere = rootViewController.presentedViewController {
                alreadySomeOneThere.presentViewController(nav1, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }else {
                rootViewController.presentViewController(nav1, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
        }
    }
}
```