# Programmatically get instance of view controller

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

I am using a class which extends `UITabBarController`. I need to set the `self.tabBarController.selectedIndex` property of my class in order to switch tabs.

Since I want to set this variable/call a method that changes this variable from another class I must have an instance of my custom class which is called `TabsController`

So far I have looked at these two posts but they involve using the storyboard and I am doing almost everything programmatically, infact this is my entire storyboard:

[image]

How do I programmatically solve this problem?

[Get Instance Of ViewController From AppDelegate In Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24638376/get-instance-of-viewcontroller-from-appdelegate-in-swift)

[Access the instance of a Viewcontroller from another in swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25204255/access-the-instance-of-a-viewcontroller-from-another-in-swift)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`UITabBarController`s are [most often used](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewControllerCatalog/Chapters/TabBarControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011313-CH3-SW2) as applications' `rootViewController`. While you are not using storyboards, after app launch, if you are setting an instance of `TabsController` as your app's window's `rootViewController`, you can refer to this instance from anywhere in your app like so:

```
if let tabsController = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate?.window??.rootViewController as? TabsController {
    tabsController.selectedIndex = 2
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This code works. Quick question, you say that if I set an instance of `TabsController` to the `rootViewController`  then I can refer to that instance by using your code. However, I just tried this code out and it worked, I have not typed any code that sets the `rootViewController`. Is this something that I should be worried about?

Comment: @Roymunson The storyboard you have in the question is most probably setting the window's root view controller to be `TabsController`. You can confirm this by looking in your [target's `General` settings tab](http://imgur.com/gallery/YqxcI) where that storyboard is set as the entry point of the application. In the storyboard `TabsController` is [set as the `Initial View Controller`](http://imgur.com/I14mM7Z), which is then set as the root view controller.

Answer (score 0):

you could try this

```
let controller = self.tabBarController.viewControllers[self.tabBarController.selectedIndex]
```